# Pan map while zooming to feature

Tags: javascript, openlayers

In my app when I click on a feature displayed on the map it zooms in and everything is centered correctly.

```
map.getView().fit(feature.getGeometry(), map.getSize())
```

However, I'd like to zoom in to some pixels left or right from this feature. I cannot see any `fit` property about that. How can I do this?